# SWT Create Two StyledText That Scroll In Tandem

Tags: java, swt, scrollbar, styledtext, tandem

I have to create two `StyledText` that scroll in tandem , All I am getting is code for creating same using `ScrolledComposites` . I have limitation of using `StyledText` only because, I am using it for other purpose as well. 
I want to create same thing  [link here](http://www.tutorialpoint.in/codes/java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/create-two-scrolledcomposites-that-scroll-in-tandem.htm) but using `StyledText`.

I tried same code replacing `ScrolledComposites` with `StyledText` but it din't allowed me to `setOrigin(x , y)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the methods `StyledText#setHorizontalPixel()` and `StyledText#setTopPixel()` (and their respecrive `get` methods) to get and set the positions:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    StyledText one = new StyledText(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    StyledText two = new StyledText(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);

    one.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);
    two.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);

    one.setText("Scroll scroll scroll\ndown down down\nto to to\nsee see see\nthe the the\nstyled styled styled\ntexts texts texts\nscroll scroll scroll\nin in in\ntandem tandem tandem");
    two.setText("Scroll scroll scroll\ndown down down\nto to to\nsee see see\nthe the the\nstyled styled styled\ntexts texts texts\nscroll scroll scroll\nin in in\ntandem tandem tandem");

    handleVerticalScrolling(one, two);
    handleHorizontalScrolling(one, two);

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(200, 100);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static void handleHorizontalScrolling(StyledText one, StyledText two)
{
    ScrollBar hOne = one.getHorizontalBar();
    ScrollBar hTwo = two.getHorizontalBar();

    hOne.addListener(SWT.Selection, e -> {
        int x = one.getHorizontalPixel();
        two.setHorizontalPixel(x);
    });
    hTwo.addListener(SWT.Selection, e -> {
        int x = two.getHorizontalPixel();
        one.setHorizontalPixel(x);
    });
}

private static void handleVerticalScrolling(StyledText one, StyledText two)
{
    ScrollBar vOne = one.getVerticalBar();
    ScrollBar vTwo = two.getVerticalBar();

    vOne.addListener(SWT.Selection, e ->
    {
        int y = one.getTopPixel();
        two.setTopPixel(y);
    });
    vTwo.addListener(SWT.Selection, e ->
    {
        int y = two.getTopPixel();
        one.setTopPixel(y);
    });
}
```